# How to maintain the order in index when creating Pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm writing for help when creating the Dataframe.

The code is shown as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,6,3],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]])
index = {'M','B','C','D'}
columns = {'x','y','z'}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data,index=index,columns=columns)
print('df_test is \n', df_test)
```

And the result is

```
     z    x    y
 B  1.0  2.0  3.0
 C  4.0  5.0  6.0
 M  2.0  6.0  3.0
 D  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But I want to maintain the order in index and data, that is, I want to get the result as:
(Please mind the order in index)

```
    z    x    y
M  1.0  2.0  3.0
B  4.0  5.0  6.0
C  2.0  6.0  3.0
D  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Anyone who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Your code is correct. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the order you should use lists for `index` (instead of sets):

```
index = ['M','B','C','D']
```

If the columns' order also matters:

```
columns = ['x','y','z']
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort_index, as below:

```
df_test.sort_index(level=['M','B','C','D'])
```

You can also use directly the name of the list, instead of the entire list, which is helpful when it's many rows, like below:

```
df_test.sort_index(level=your_index)
```

where in this case is

```
your_index = ['M','B','C','D']
```

(avoid naming your_index as 'index' as you did in your question, because this name is already used from Python)

Comment: Yeah, it works as expected. However, when many rows exists, use list may be better as shown by @rftr

Comment: What do you mean? My solution uses list as well. You can also use directly the name of the list, instead of the entire list, which is helpful when it's many rows, like below:

`df_test.sort_index(level=your_index)`

Comment: Oh, I got it. I misunderstood your suggestion before, it is another proper solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept some of the answers, given that your problem was resolved, so that the question leaves from unanswered queue. Cheers